# Contar numeros sorteados em uma tabela de loteria

Tags: mysql, count

Sou novo nos estudos de BD e tenho uma tabela com os resultados da lotofácil onde gostaria de fazer um count que buscasse, por exemplo, quantas vezes a dezena 20 foi sorteada.
Já fiz vários testes porém só consegui coluna a coluna e se coloco um count geral ele aponta para valores considerando as datas e dá errado.
Abaixo uma parte da imagem do meu banco.

[image: Sorteios]

Comment: Poderia mostrar os seus testes falhados e um retorno do resultado desse exemplo que mostra?

Comment: 'code'SELECT COUNT(18) FROM `sorteiosanteriores`'code' foi o primeiro que resultou na contagem informando os dados constantes no campo de datas. Outra tentativa foi 'code'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sorteiosanteriores` WHERE Bola1 = 18 AND Bola2 = 18'code' que retornou zerado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta resposta ignora o facto de o valor 20 não se poder repetir visto ser uma das regras de negócio este valor não poder estar repetido em várias colunas do mesmo sorteio.

```
SET @valor = 20;
select 
      (select count(Bola1) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola1 = @valor) 
    + (select count(Bola2) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola2 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola3) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola3 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola4) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola4 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola5) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola5 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola6) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola6 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola7) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola7 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola8) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola8 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola9) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola9 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola10) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola10 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola11) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola11 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola12) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola12 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola13) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola13 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola14) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola14 = @valor)
    + (select count(Bola15) from sorteiosanteriores where Bola15 = @valor);
```

O que isto faz é contar em todas as colunas o valor colocado na variável @valor e no fim retorna o valor da soma das contagens.

Para uma resposta baseada na regra de negócio veja a resposta do [@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/392045/49505).

Comment: Funcionou. Consegui gerar os cálculo e agora vou aplicar nas consultas. Obrigado

Answer (score 6):

Como se trata de um sorteio em que não há repetição de valores nas colunas, pode usar o operador `IN`:

```
SELECT
      COUNT(*)
FROM
      sorteiosanteriores
WHERE
      20 IN (bola1,bola2,bola3,bola4,bola5,bola6 ... bola15)
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cfd60/1)**.

Agora, precisa ver se essa modelagem "horizontal" é a melhor solução. Provavelmente uma tabela relacionada seja melhor do que um monte de colunas como mesmo propósito.

Atenção: esta *query* foi otimizada para o caso da "lotofácil", e conta o **número de linhas** que o 20 é retornado, independente dele ter ocorrido uma  ou várias vezes na mesma linha. Para contagem geral, vide a resposta do @MauroAlmeida ou o trecho a seguir.

### Contando múltiplas ocorrências

```
SELECT
      SUM((bola1=20)+(bola2=20)+(bola3=20)+ ... +(bola15=20))
      AS quantidade
FROM
     sorteiosanteriores
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6219c/1)**.

Isto funciona de uma maneira muito simples. O `true` em MySQL tem o valor 1, e o `false` 0. Assim, basta somar a quantidade de igualdades por linha, e agregar com `SUM`.

Esta segunda opção conta a quantidade total de ocorrências dos números, incluindo repetições na mesma linha.

Comment: As duas respostas trouxeram o resultado que preciso. A do @MauroAlmeida tem um pouco mais de códigos, a do Bacco com menos. Agora vou começar a aplicar nos estudos que estou desenvolvendo. Grato a todos pela contribuição